# Datetimepicker and monthcalendar changing appearance

Tags: c#, winforms, datetimepicker, monthcalendar

I'm trying to add either monthcalendar or DateTimePicker to my C# project (Visual Studio 2019 Winforms) and for some reason, the calendar has a different appearance in editing mode and in running mode.

This is how it looks when I add it to my form:

[image: this is how it looks when i add it to my form]

and this is how it looks when I run my program:

[image: this is how it looks when its in running mode]

Is there a way to solve this problem? Thanks for the help.

Comment: You have commented out/not set/disabled `Application.EnableVisualStyles();`. The original visual is derived from the system theme. The other one is the pre-Vista rendering. VisualStyles determine the rendering style.

Comment: @Jimi oh thats right. I fixed it thank you so much